# Is it possible to see what is my connection path/final tor node in this identity?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I remember that some versions ago tor had a pop-down menu where it was possible to see the path that the connection went through. Has it become totally hidden or was it moved somewhere?

How do I look up my connection path/final node country *after* I'm already launched tor?